# Proper way to pan and move camera in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Right now I'm panning by glRotating before rendering everything, and i'm moving the camera by gltranslating. I feel as if this is wrong since im essentially moving the scene, not the camera. What is the proper way to move the camera?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Milo,If you get any idea about pan functionality now means. please suggest any sample code for Pan Functionality in OpenGL Es2.0 in Android.I saw more links, but, i could not get any clear idea about that pan functionality..

Comment: @sje397 The link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually 'moving the scene around the camera' is the proper way in OpenGL.

This is due to the fact that OpenGL combines the view and model matrices into the modelview matrix. (look [here](http://songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) for more details)

Obvious the lookat function (as mentioned above) is an easy way to move a (virtual) camera but i found that it doesn't work for OpenGL3.

I'd suggest to use the excellent [glm library](http://glm.g-truc.net) to setup the transformation matrices for OpenGL3.

Kind Regards,
Florian

Comment: Hi Florian, can u please suggest any sample code for Pan Functionality in OpenGL Es2.0 in Android.I saw more links, but, i could not get any clear idea about that pan functionality..

Answer (score 2):

Moving the scene and the camera is essentially the same thing. One being the negative of the other.
The usual way of implementing it is to have a camera class with absolute coordinates and direction, then you just put

```
glTranslate(-camera)
glRotate(-camera)
```

at the top in your display function.

Comment: Hi Takoi,I am also tryied thispanning, while touch event.but, its not work for me. can u give some example code for this pan functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[gluLookAt](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) is how you move the camera.

Comment: @Milo: You can pan it with gluLookAt too.

Comment: That's a link to Python bindings doc. [Here are C API docs.](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)

Comment: @Craig McQueen: Thnx for the link.

Comment: Hi, that link (page not found error)not open.. please can you give some example program for this panning functionality in opengles2.0 in android..