# Pan functionality in OpenGL ES2.0 in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have developed Auto-cad App in android using OpenGL ES2.0. Here I have done for drawing multiple lines and circles etc.. But, I am struggle in Pan Functionality.[ Explanation For Pan Functionality : just drag the GLSurfaceview to top, bottom,left and right side using touch event].

Here am used for 2d scene GLSurfaceview to draw the line, circle, dashed line etc.. Here I am doing for panning option to that glsurfaceview..

Please any one give any sample code or suggestion to complete the panning Functionality in Android OpenGL ES2.0.

I refereed more links like this.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48372/all-of-my-matrix-functions-not-working-opengl-es-2-0

gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48372/all-of-my-matrix-functions-not-working-opengl-es-2-0

http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs184/fa09/resources/sec09_camera.pdf

[opengl panning with glulookat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246102/opengl-panning-with-glulookat?rq=1)

http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/gluLookAt.html

http://songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/

http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

[Proper way to pan and move camera in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632327/proper-way-to-pan-and-move-camera-in-opengl)

[OpenGL ES 2.0 Pinch and Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115787/opengl-es-2-0-pinch-and-zoom)

But, I cant do that pan functionality..
can u suggest any panning sample code for this Panning Functionality opengles2.0 in android.
please anyone help me out from this struggle..

Thanks Advance....

Comment: Im also looking for how to move the GLSurfaceView in opengl es2.0 android. Is it possible? Someone please provide a sample code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom class extended from TextureView and implement the onMeasure() and onLayout() methods.  TextureView will display OpenGL ES rendering but is much more flexible than GLSurfaceView and will follow the normal layout hierarchy in Android which allows views to be moved on the display.  It would look something like this:

```
class CustomTextureView extends TextureView
{
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {}
    protected void onLayout(boolean bChanged, int iLeft, int iTop, int iRight, int iBottom)
    {}
}
```

This article will help with more details on using TextureView:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: Hi Clay, Thank you for your reply. can u give some code for do the panning functionality in GLsurafaceview.

Comment: There are several ways to do this.  If your entire Auto CAD image is in one texture, you can change the texture coordinates to cause its position to pan within the SurfaceTexture.   Another approach would be to translate the geometry before it is rendered, with a translation matrix.

Comment: Hi Clay,This is code able to draw lines.after drawn lines,i cant pan the background scene.Here I had pan issue. here i used code for pan functionality.but, i cant do pan.here i used GLSurfaceview for panning. what i need it for?= just drag the GLSurfaceview from top,bottom,left,right side. move the background GLSurfaceview.

Comment: Hi Clay, My code is useful to identify my pan issue. please help me to come out from this problem..

Comment: Hi Clay, here i did not use any auto cad images.i dont want to pan any images. i want to pan the background GLSurfaceview scene like Desktop Auto cad.here i used setlookatm and translation, rotation matrix for panning. but, i cant get any clear idea to solve my issue.if possible give my any sample code. its useful for me..

Comment: Hi Clay,thank for your reply.This is the link of my code. http://www.mediafire.com/download/55lp59gdq78a3q3/LineDraw_Test.zip